# Pig: After join dump is throwing ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias C

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Below is my requirement:

Input:

```
0104919 ,08476,48528,2016,2016-08-29

00104919 ,08476,48528,2016,2016-09-05

00104919 ,08476,48528,2016,2016-09-12

00104919 ,08476,48528,2017,2016-08-29
```

Output after join should be:

```
 2,00104919 ,08476,48528,2016,2016-09-05,2016-09-12

 3,00104919 ,08476,48528,2016,2016-09-12,2016-08-29
```

Below is my code:

```
    TABL = LOAD '/TABL/part-r-00000' using PigStorage('~') AS (a,b,c,d,e,f);
    pre_Q1 = FOREACH TABL generate a,b,c,d,e;
    DIST = DISTINCT pre_Q1;
    ORDR = ORDER DIST BY *;
    Q1 = rank ORDR;
    Q2 = FOREACH Q1 GENERATE rank_ORDR + 1 AS rank_Q2, a, b, c, d, e;
    Q_join = join Q2 by (rank_Q2, a, b, c, d), Q1 by (rank_ORDR, a, b, c, d);
    C = limit Q_join 100;
    dump C;
```

I am getting the below error.
Can someone point out what must be causing the below error.

```
Failed Jobs:
JobId   Alias   Feature Message Outputs
job_1474127474437_528208        C,Q2,Q_join     HASH_JOIN       Message: Job failed!

Input(s):
Successfully read 5235587 records (1516199217 bytes) from: "/TABL/part-r-00000"

Output(s):

Counters:
Total records written : 0
Total bytes written : 0
Spillable Memory Manager spill count : 0
Total bags proactively spilled: 0
Total records proactively spilled: 0

Job DAG:
job_1474127474437_528166        ->      job_1474127474437_528185,
job_1474127474437_528185        ->      job_1474127474437_528190,
job_1474127474437_528190        ->      job_1474127474437_528204,
job_1474127474437_528204        ->      job_1474127474437_528206,
job_1474127474437_528206        ->      job_1474127474437_528208,
job_1474127474437_528208        ->      null,
null


2017-01-04 04:02:37,407 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate - Application state is completed. FinalApplicationStatus=SUCCEEDED. Redirecting to job history server
2017-01-04 04:02:37,569 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate - Application state is completed. FinalApplicationStatus=SUCCEEDED. Redirecting to job history server
2017-01-04 04:02:37,729 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate - Application state is completed. FinalApplicationStatus=SUCCEEDED. Redirecting to job history server
2017-01-04 04:02:37,887 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate - Application state is completed. FinalApplicationStatus=SUCCEEDED. Redirecting to job history server
2017-01-04 04:02:37,945 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Some jobs have failed! Stop running all dependent jobs
2017-01-04 04:02:37,945 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias C
Details at logfile: /var/log/gphd/pig/pig.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify the first line as below :

```
TABL = LOAD '/TABL/part-r-00000' using PigStorage(',') AS (a,b,c,d,e,f);
```

And watch out to the `space` at the end of the column `a`, it may affect the join !

Comment: I forgot to mention, the data is '~' delimited that's why I have used PigStorage('~'). Also I tried join as Q_join = join Q2 by rank_Q2, Q1 by rank_ORDR; but it is still giving the same error.

Comment: @SurajSingh dont forget, just copy and paste a five line of your input as it is, and you can add many `dump` to know where is the problem.